Conectividad de ftp con máquina cnc
Tengo una máquina cnc del año aprox 2005 la cual se puede conectar con ftp a través de un RJ45, al intentar conectar desde el ordenador, habiendo añadido la ip estatica y la submascara me rechaza la conexión, adjunto la información útil, y gracias

¿Las imagenes son de la máquina CNC o del PC? ¿Qué error te da? ¿Cuales son los parámetros IP del PC? ¿Hay un firewall o router entremedio? ¿Puedes hacer ping al CNC? ¿Puede acceder a la puerta 21 desde el PC (usando netcat, por ejemplo)?

Que software es ese?

Esa es la máquina cnc, si hago ping si q recibo señal, pero al conectarme con ftp la conexión me la rechaza, lo de netcat no lo he probado pero por ftp por consola no me dejaba, no hay fire wall esta conectada directamente a la máquina

Puedes probar con un telnet hacia la IP y el puerto. Así puedes saber también si se puede establecer conexión. También puedes ver puertos abiertos, en la configuracion que has pasado está el puerto 21 y el 8193... Mira a ver si están abiertos

Prueba a hacer "ftp test.rebex.net", con usuario "anonymous" y como password tu email (no lo chequea) para descartar algún problema en tu PC.

No es un problema con el pc porq he testado con el Windows xp q viene con la máquina y un Windows 10

¿Cual es la IP del PC?

Es 192.168.1.10
